# Laravel 5.2.x - Intervention/Image - Call to a member function encode() on null

Tags: laravel, intervention, laravel-5

I have created a repository to manage the upload image using `Intervention/Image`library but when I try to save an image I get `Call to a member function encode() on null`.

This is my interface:

```php
namespace App\Repositories\MeetMount\ImageUploader;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

interface ImageContract {
    public function getExt($filename);
    public function setFolder($folderName);
    public function getRandomFilename($fileName);
    public function addWatermark($watermarkName);
    public function resize($width, $height);
    public function getFileName();
    public function save(Request $file);
}
```

This is my concrete class:

```php
namespace App\Repositories\MeetMount\ImageUploader;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Intervention\Image\Image;

class InterventionImageRepository implements ImageContract {

    /**
     * @var Image
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var $folder
     */
    private $folder;

    /**
     * InterventionImageRepository constructor.
     *
     * @param Image $image
     */
    public function __construct( Image $image )
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    /**
     * Restituisce l'estensione dell'immagine
     *
     * @param $fileName
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExt( $fileName )
    {
        $pos = strrpos( $fileName, '.' );
        $ext = substr( $fileName, $pos, strlen( $fileName ) );

        return $ext;
    }

    /**
     * Imposta la cartella dove salvare l'immagine
     *
     * @param $folderName
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setFolder( $folderName )
    {
        $folderPath = public_path( $folderName );

        if( ! File::exists( $folderPath ) )
        {
            File::makeDirectory( $folderPath );
        }

        $this->folder = $folderPath;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRandomFilename( $fileName )
    {
        // TODO: Implement getRandomFilename() method.
    }

    /**
     * Aggiungi watermark
     *
     * @param $watermarkName
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addWatermark( $watermarkName )
    {
        $watermarkPath = public_path( 'images/watermarks/' . $watermarkName );
        $this->image->insert( $watermarkPath );

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Salva il file
     *
     * @param $file
     * @return $this
     */
    public function save( Request $request )
    {
        $file = $request->file('immagine');

        $fileFolder = $this->folder . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $this->image->save( $fileFolder );

        return $this;

    }

    public function getFileName()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getFileName() method.
    }

    public function resize( $width, $height )
    {
        // TODO: Implement resize() method.
    }
}
```

and this is the store method:

```php
public function store( CreatePlaceRequest $request )
{
    $this->imageRepository->setFolder('cartella-prova')->save($request);
}
```

When I submit the form I get:

> FatalErrorException in Image.php line 119:
>       Call to a member function encode() on null
>       in Image.php line 119
>       at FatalErrorException->__construct() in HandleExceptions.php line 133
>       at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in HandleExceptions.php line 118
>       at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0
>       at Image->encode() in Image.php line 139
>       at Image->save() in InterventionImageRepository.php line 96
>       at InterventionImageRepository->save() in PlacesController.php line 80
>       at PlacesController->store() in Controller.php line 76

The problem should be here: `at Image->save() in InterventionImageRepository.php line 96`

and that line is in the concrete class, in the save method:

```php
$this->image->save( $fileFolder );
```

Can someone help me to find the problem?

Comment: i have implemented  interventions image with laravel. Just let me know which laravel version you are using.

Comment: the version is 5.2.*

Comment: When you initiate the repository, do you supply an actual image? Since it's in the constructor, I mean.

Comment: used  "intervention/image": "dev-master", with composer ? ?

Comment: @PunitGajjar I have `"intervention/image": "^2.3"`, should I change? @Joel No, in the construct I just insert the lbrary

Comment: I meant the constructor of the repository. You have this: `public function __construct( Image $image ) { $this->image = $image; }`. So if you don't supply an image when you initiate the repository, `$this->image` won't have an actual image.

Comment: Right, I have removed it from the construct and added `$image = Image::make($fileFolder);` int the `save` method but now it says `Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\Image::make()`

Comment: You're importing the wrong class at the top. Please have a look at the installation instructions here http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation. I would follow the Laravel integration instructions to get a facade, but that's up to you.

Comment: try with the dev master. dont go for older version .

Answer (score 0):

According to the error:

> Call to a member function encode() on null ...

This means you are trying to save an image while it doesn't received an image - `null`.

The problem is with `save` function in your `InterventionImageRepository` class. I've modified it to check if there is an image or not.

Also consider your image filed name has typo(`immagine`). Make sure you use the same word in your form input feild with type=file. Else correct it to have same name both in `controller/class` files and frond end `views`. Also make sure you are using enctype="multipart/form-data" in your `<form>` tag.
`<form method="post" action="target-path" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Otherwise files will not send to server along with the form values.

```
/**
 * Salva il file
 *
 * @param $file
 * @return $this
 */
public function save( Request $request )
{
    //first check if the file received
    if($request->hasFile('immagine')){
        $file = $request->file('immagine');
        $fileFolder = $this->folder . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->image->save( $fileFolder );

        return $this;
    }else{
        //Do some necessary outputs here
        //may be store a message to session and display it to user in the view
        //or return a boolean value and check for it in your store method
    }
}
```

Refer to this Laravel's official documentation and improve your scripts: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files